# A bug in chat has taken my voice away. My letters vanish as I write them. Please send help

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

This is going to sound insane. I swear I'm not insane. You have to believe me. *I need you to believe me.*

Mobile chat won't let me type letters. Punctuation? Fine. Letters? They completely vanish as soon as I type them. I don't know where they're going. I think they're being eaten. Swallowed up, maybe into the place all the missing pencils go, to rejoin their kin.

[I'm not the only one who's seen this bug, either.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33798119#33798119) I know it's real. It has to be real. But unlike for my good friend doppelgreener, a simple refresh did not fix my plight.

Please send help to your nearest Huawei Nexus 6P running Android 7.0.0. My Google Keyboard and Chrome 54.0.2840.85 are helping me in this fight, but I don't know what to do, or who to turn to. I pray now to the SE overlords, and to the many voices of meta, having lost all other hope.

Save me from my silence.

Comment: This occurs for me on other chats I visit on other (non-SE) sites, so it may be a browser/keyboard bug and not a bug that is in Stack Exchange's control.

Comment: (That's definitely possible. I posted it here because I've only seen this on SE chat, but because it's an intermittent failure, it might not be an SE bug.)

Comment: Sounds like my keyboard shortcuts on the mobile web issue: [Mobile search made impossible with keyboard shortcuts enabled](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/286345) Can you try disabling shortcuts (go to the desktop version, go to preferences, disable keyboard shortcuts, refresh on mobile). Another indicator there's overlap here would be if the `?` question mark didn't work.

Comment: having the same issues now and then, mostly after locking the screen while in my chatroom of preference and returning. refreshing usually fixes the issue

Comment: For me closing the Chrome app and reopening works.